# Text not updating dynamically with d3 after using d3.exit().remove()

Tags: html, d3.js

So I am building an interactive dashboard, in that whenever you click on a button the bar graph changes something like this (https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_button_data_hard.html)

In my code, I am trying to update the title of the bar graph as well by doing this

```
var t = svg_bar_graph_time_date.selectAll("label").data(data_bar_graph_time_date)

                t.enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("x", width_time_date/2)
                .attr("y", 20)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("font-size", "16px")
                .text(date);
                
                t.exit().remove()
```

But instead of changing the title of the bar graph, the new title is overlapping over the previous one.
How can I remove the previous title and change it new one?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're biding the data to elements that have the `label` class (unless you're selecting a `<label>` element, which doesn't seem to be the case)...

```
var t = svg_bar_graph_time_date.selectAll(".label")
    .data(data_bar_graph_time_date);
```

... you need to apply that class to the enter selection, and merge it with the update selection:

```
t = t.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x", width_time_date/2)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-size", "16px")
    .merge(t)
    .text(date);
```

If you're using a D3 version without merge, change the update selection:

```
t.text(date);
```

Also, it's strange that you're binding data but never use it (you're using `date`, but isn't clear where that is coming from). If that's intended, drop the exit selection and just do `data([true])` or any other non-empty one-element array.